# mongoose save populated doc with at least 1 dead required ref

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to alter a shared doc

Info may be relevant to the users involved even after 1 of them terminated their account.

consider:

```
const USER = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}
})

const EVENT = new Schema({
  initiator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  members: [{
    enthusiasm: {type: Number, min: 0, max: 10}
    member: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true}
  }],
  hideFrom: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
})
```

Event data will still be available throughout app history. Though a user may terminate his account, but the data still has to be presented. While so, a user may request to hide this data from his dashboard.

Problem is - the data is already populated and once the initiator gets `populated` - if he's deleted - I get a field of `null`.

the error I'm receiving is:

> Event validation failed: members.0.member: Path `member` is required

Which is in response to trying to save the received `null` into the doc instead of the user which is now gone.

Any suggestions about what can I do to `save()` this doc after it was populated and altered ? when having a field of `null` I cannot find a way to retrieve that lost `_id` unless I am re-querying the doc and refilling the lost teeth. It may be trivial for the `initiator` field but I do not see how it is possible for the `members` array.

EDIT - adding a mirroring object:

```
AlteredPopulatedEventToSave = {
  initiator: null,
  members: [
    {
      enthusiasm: 6,
      member: {_id: "wrwh89242h49284h2fk23fj", name: "Member One"}
    },
    {
      enthusiasm: 4,
      member: null
    }
  ],
  hideFrom: ["wrwh89242h49284h2fk23fj"]

AlteredPopulatedEventToSave.save() // <--- error: path `initiator` is required
```

Comment: What does the object look like before you try to .save() it? Could you just remove the `required: true` from the `members.member`?

Comment: @Pysul I _could_ but it will weaken the doc validation process. Also, it will completely remove the corresponding users from the actions they have made, and in case of account renewal, the data attached to them will be lost.
I added an example where a user requests to append himself to the `hideFrom` array